# value for specific column type not updating on bulk upload

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise

I am trying to create a bulk upload for sharepoint site

It has some content types

For example, for contenttype `Document`, I am sending the values in the below fomat

```
{FieldId:"Some_Id",FieldType:"Text",FieldValue:"Value"}
```

This format works when the `FieldType` is Text  (for column type `single line of text`)

But for other column types I am not able to figure out the FieldType that I need to send

I tried `DateTime` for column type `Publishing Schedule Start Date` and `Choice` for `Choice`

After doing some [research i found that](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/sharepoint-blog/what-is-the-data-type-of-the-yesno-field-16929) for field type of `Yes/No` in sharepoint the dataType is `boolean`and for DateTime it is `Date And Time` similarly where can i find the list of datatypes for all the field types(multiple line of text, user groups, Meta data etc)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the field type, you may not be just able to set the field value like you do it with simple text field type. E.g., with multi-choice fields you would do it like this:

```
$choicevalues = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldMultiChoiceValue;
$choicevalues.Add("Green");            
$choicevalues.Add("Blue");            
$i["multiplechoicefield"] = $l.Fields["multiplechoicefield"].ParseAndSetValue($i,$choicevalues);            
$i["multiplechoicefield"].ToString();            
$i["multiplechoicefield"] = $choicevalues;            
$i.Update();
```

I'm not going to copy&paste [this LONG article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20831.sharepoint-a-complete-guide-to-getting-and-setting-fields-using-powershell.aspx) here, but I believe it will tell you how to set values of different field types. It uses PowerShell, but regardless of how you're doing it, it should still give the idea for each field type.

Comment: Thanks @palo 
Where can i find the list of dataTypes available in sharepoint?
For instance, dataType of Yes/No field is Boolean(pls refer to my updated question)